# Django breaking css after using if statement

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to add a dropdown list into my navbar that i created using bootstrap but whenever i put the dropdown menu into the if statement to loop categories into a list, the css breaks.

[without if statement(only for loop)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz8aa.png)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark nav-color fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}" ><b>Lorem Ipsum</b></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
   
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link active dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
            Categories
          </a>
          
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            {% for item in cat_menu %}
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category' item|slugify %}">{{ item }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
          
        </li>
    
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a href="{% url 'blogposts'%}" class="nav-link" id="hover-change">Blog Posts <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a href="{% url 'personalinfo'%}" class="nav-link">About Me <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'create-post'%}">Create Post <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'create-category'%}">Create Category <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout'%}">Logout <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        {% else %}
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a href="{% url 'blogposts'%}" class="nav-link" id="hover-change">Blog Posts <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a href="{% url 'personalinfo'%}" class="nav-link">About Me <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}" >Login <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}" >Register <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
  </nav>
```

**After Including If Statement:**
[after including if statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1iK8.png)

```
{% if cat_menu %}
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link active dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
            Categories
          </a>
          
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            {% for item in cat_menu %}
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category' item|slugify %}">{{ item }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
          
        </li>
        {% endif %}
```

I've tried putting the ul tag into the if statement but it just gave me a blank list

**Edit:** I decided to put the dropdown list in both `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` and `{% else %}` tags instead of leaving on top.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">  
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a href="{% url 'blogposts'%}" class="nav-link" id="hover-change">Blog Posts <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a href="{% url 'personalinfo'%}" class="nav-link">About Me <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'create-post'%}">Create Post <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'create-category'%}">Create Category <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout'%}">Logout <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    {% if cat_menu %}
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link active dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
            Categories
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            {% for item in cat_menu %}
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category' item|slugify %}">{{ item }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
      </div>
      {% endif %}   
    {% else %}
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a href="{% url 'blogposts'%}" class="nav-link" id="hover-change">Blog Posts <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a href="{% url 'personalinfo'%}" class="nav-link">About Me <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    {% if cat_menu %}
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link active dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
            Categories
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            {% for item in cat_menu %}
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category' item|slugify %}">{{ item }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
            </li>
      {% endif %}  
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}" >Login <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}" >Register <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now there's a gap between buttons: [navbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kblow.png)

Comment: Your `<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">` is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

You do not seem to be closing the first `<ul>` bracket with class `navbar-nav mr-auto`. Place the opening `<ul>` bracket outside the if statement for dropdown list item.

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

    {% if cat_menu %}
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
```

Then close the list by placing `</ul>` before `</div></nav>`

```
     {% endif %}
     </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I've tried this and now the navbar looks like this: https://imgur.com/WDxpvfQ